# Printing chars from 2d array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How do you print chars from a 2D array, column by column instead of row by row? Also how do you get the chars to populate the array? I know you have to use for loop but I keep getting  strings which are read row by row.

```
String command = args[0]; 
    String Text = args[1]; //leters to be 

    char letters [] = Text.toCharArray(); 
    int m = Text.length(); //number of letters to be decrypted/encrypted


    if (command.equals("-encrypt")) {

        if ( m / (int) Math.sqrt(m) == Math.sqrt(m) ) { //if m is a perfect square no. eg.4,9,16

            int RootM = (int) Math.sqrt(m); //find depth and width of grid, square therfore depth = width
            char [][] box = new char [RootM][RootM]; //define and create grid 

        for (int i=0; i<RootM; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<RootM; j++) {

                box[i] = letters; //change this to read each column
                System.out.print(Text); //displays encrypted text
            }
        }
     }

        else if     ( m / (int) Math.sqrt(m) != Math.sqrt(m) ) { //non perfect square digits

        int RootM = (int) Math.pow((Math.sqrt(m))+1,2); //overall size of 2d array (depth*width)
        int RootN1 = (int) Math.sqrt(RootM); //length of rows & columns

        char [][] box = new char [RootN1][RootN1]; //define dimensions of 2d array

            for (int i=0; i<RootN1; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<RootN1; j++) {
                    box[j] = letters; //change this to read each column
            System.out.println(Text); //displays encrypted text
```

Comment: just added my method above

Comment: your example is not related to 2d arrays

Answer (score 1):

```
char [][] box = new char [5][3];//5 rows, 3 columns
for(int i =0;i<3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {//Iterate rows
        System.out.println(box[j][i]);//Print colmns
    }   
}
```

Comment: i get a message that says invalid expression on the --> System.out.println(char [j][i]) says char is an invalid token

Comment: im trying to put in the argument "-encrypt abcd" so that it read acbd

Comment: This is just samplecode.You need to initialize your array as per your logic.

Comment: when i create the 2d array, does it automatically populate with the array "letters" ? or do i have to write a statement to populate it?  hence it prints each char on one line.

Comment: thats the thing how do I initialise the array?

Comment: also hwo do you convert string abcd to char a,b,c,d? please i googled this so much i just dont get it